# App Expose, show XCode project name

Tags: macos, xcode, expose

Few versions of OSX ago, the project name was shown under the XCode window, when app expose was used... now just the open file name is shown, which totally useless

I cannot navigate to my open project and it's irritating as hell

How to show Xcode project name under the expose opened window

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPDATE**: the solution below, sadly, no longer works after update to Xcode 8, because Apple shut down plugins support :( If anyone knows a working solution for Xcode 8 and above, please, write a comment below this answer to notify me, I'll be very grateful!

---

It can be done using the [ProjectWindowName](https://github.com/sleifer/ProjectWindowName) Xcode plugin. You can install it via [Alcatraz](http://alcatraz.io). Alcatraz is not officially supported, so sometimes plugins stop working after Xcode updates (reinstallation usually helps). Or some plugins might deactivate after an update, because the compatibility UUID for the new Xcode version is not listed among compatibility UUIDs for the plugin.

I'm writing it here, because I'm unsure, whether the ProjectWindowName plugin was updated to support the latest Xcode. So if you installed Alcatraz, installed the plugin, relaunched Xcode two times (I don't know why, but Xcode can't seem to be able to show recent project after the first relaunch), and still project name is not shown in the expose mode, run the script from the accepted answer in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30361228/why-are-my-xcode-plugins-such-as-clang-format-installed-with-alcatraz-no-longe).

Because I'm running the latest OS X 10.11.4 with the latest Xcode 7.3 (7D175) at the moment, and project name in expose works fine :)

Comment: Worked, great!!!

Comment: @PeterLapisu, I'm glad I was able to help) I missed this feature too)

Comment: To make it work with Xcode 7.3, add its UUID to `plugin-info.plist` before you build the project:
`ACA8656B-FEA8-4B6D-8E4A-93F4C95C362C`